# Can I use HCPL-7840 Isolation Amplifier as a non-differential output device?

Tags: power-electronics, voltage-measurement

[image]
What I am trying to do is build a basic MPPT boost converter. To implement the MPPT, I need to feed the voltage across the solar panel into the microcontroller. I thought having some isolation between the power converter and the microcontroller(I am using an Arduino UNO) was a good idea.
To isolate the grounds, I decided to use the HCPL-7840 Isolation Amplifier.

As shown in the above schematic, I have connected one side of the IC to the resistive divider. However, I wish to feed the differential voltage of the output to the microcontroller.

Instead of using another OP-AMP stage, to convert the differential output to a non differential output, can I connect the - terminal of the output to the microcontroller ground and the + terminal of the output to the microcontroller port?

Would this cause any issues? Or is it recommended to use another OP-AMP stage then feed it to the microcontroller?

Comment: True, the ACS712 does have isolation but the resistive divider arrangement I've used to measure the solar panel input voltage does not have isolation.

Comment: Oh, I see what the circuit is intended to do. I had the the ACS712 backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't connect the isolation amp negative output to ground. This is because the common mode output voltage in the datasheet is listed at mid-supply (~2.5V). That means at 0V output, both positive and negative outputs of the isolation amp will 2.5V and the outputs will move away from each other about 2.5V as the output signal voltage increases. Connecting the negative output to ground would mean forcing it to drive a short. If the isolation amp had a separate Vref input so you could set the common mode voltage then you could connect both Vref to ground which would allow you to safely connect the negative output to ground.

A sloppy approach would be to leave the negative output voltage open or connect it to ground through a large resistor and then digitally offset your ADC reading at the positive output by 2.5V and multiply it by two.

What's the input voltage? Judging from the resistor ratio it's about 30V?

You don't need isolation for that. Just add a diode clamp to the output of the divider to clamp the voltage if the divider output voltage gets too high, either from the divider input voltage being too high or from R2 failing open and reducing the divider ratio to 1. The diode clamp then uses the R2 for current limiting to prevent the diode from frying when clamping.

In addition to that, you can also split R2 into two series resistors so that if one fails short the other resistor still remains to act as a current limiting resistor so that the diode clamp the increased output from the divider without frying. This also provides current limiting even in the event of resistors failing short if the clamp diode also fails short.

---

Or you can forget the clamp diode, and simply use more than two resistors for R2 and you step increase the divider ratio more than you need to, you can tolerate one R2 resistor failing short and still have the voltage be at a safe level. If the divider ratio is conservative enough and you split R2 into enough resistors you can survive failures of multiple R2 resistors.

A similar approach can be taken to protect against R1 failing open except you use parallel resistors for R1.

And on top of all that, you can still add the clamp diode in case enough R2 resistors fail short and/or enough R1 resistors fail open to reduce the divider ratio to the point the output voltage is unsafe. All you need is enough resistance remaining in R2 to do the current limiting.

Comment: I am going for isolation cause I once fried my laptop due to faulty grounding. Isolating the microcontroller from the power stage is a good practice, is what I heard from my professor. Besides, I will try connecting the - to the Supply ground through a high resistance as you have suggested. One more thing, I have connected the - of the input terminal to the power converter ground. This should not cause any issues right?

Also, thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Comment: @Narutorunner11 The input should be okay.